# Weird process running every day, I don't know what it is

Tags: process

I have this weird process running every day on my computer. It's called `Intelligent Team.exe`. It doesn't take much memory, nor it makes my computer run slower, it just runs every day on startup and I just want to know what this thing is.

Comment: Do a search on your C drive, find where that exe file is located, this might give you a clue as to what it is or what program it is associated with.

Comment: The only 2 folders that I found were a folder in the Microsoft folder and it was something like AppCrash_(random numbers and letters)_IntelligentTeam_(random numbers and letters) and the other one was in AppData/Roaming/Intelligent team and it had an exe file in it named Intelligent Team.exe and a .dat file named ym0ub.. What do you think?

Comment: I read the properties of the exe file and it had all permissions you could possibly have of the system, Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, Read, Write and all that stuff..

Comment: Its not a Windows file, looks like malware or virus to me.

Comment: I'm going to wait for more people to tell me what they think.. I'm honestly pretty concerned..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed sounds very suspicious - If your computer is in a work environment with IT staff, you should speak to them about it.

Otherwise, download Malwarebytes and decent AV software and run it through your computer.

Comment: I used a few antivirus softwares earlier but none of them mentioned this file.

Comment: And the weird part is that my computer is still doing fine with this thing on it.. I've had this process since 5th of July.. I don't think it's something really serious, but if someone finds the answer please tell me.

Comment: Did you use Malwarebytes ?  AV is not quite the same thing as Anti Malware.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, I did scan my system fully and it did find about 50 different adware viruses and the Intelligent Team thing was in there too.. Just a little adware, nothing important. Thanks for the help. :D